# how do i replay macros in ideavim like regular vim?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

Record my macro the usual way: `qa ..do stuff.. q`

Try to replay it 5 times but it only runs once: `"5@a`

How do I run it multiple times?

Opened bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1402

Comment: I upvoted that bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1402

Comment: Why do you use `"` before `5@a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that action is supported by the plugin.

I'm not seeing a [unit test](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/test/org/jetbrains/plugins/ideavim/action/MacroActionTest.java) in their code for this.

I scanned their [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM?q=macro) but didn't see any existing report for this behavior. It would probably be a good idea to open one up.

Comment: boooo how dare they not have the one thing i use! I kinda surprised, I thought everyone used this- at least heavy vim users. I just opened a bug report, thanks! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1402

Answer (score 5):

Update to accepted answer: the issue seems to be fixed.

It doesn't work with the " before macro replay though. However, the macro replay doesn't work in my normal vim with it either

At least this works for me both in vim 7.4 and in Idea 19.2 with IdeaVim 0.54:

```
qq button pressing... q14@q
```

Also, a comment in [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1402](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1402) shows that it seems to work for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Phpstorm 2020.1 and Ideavim 0.60, and this seems to be fixed.