# use vim macros in Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I am using ideavim in pycharm. I want to use macros when writing code. But vim mapping macros does not work. I want to record with q and easy to use macros which repeat with @.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i replay macros in ideavim like regular vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233795/how-do-i-replay-macros-in-ideavim-like-regular-vim)

Comment: Thanks! It's only to wait

Comment: `qq<dosmth>q` and then `5@q` works fine (IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5, IdeaVim 0.48)

Comment: @boriselec Thanks, it worked perfectly